# [OpenERP]How to get response of transaction status from paypal into openerp form?

Tags: paypal, odoo

I am having a openerp application which includes option pay with paypal. After payment i want to show staus of transaction to users. How to get response of transaction status from paypal into openerp form?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what PayPal service you are using.  For example if you are using Website Payments Pro DoDirectPayment API or Express Checkout, you should be getting a response back to your system after the buyer completes the payment.  You can then display the result on the screen. If you are using Website Payments Standard, you can use [PDT](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN) to get a response back to the return page to display to your buyer.  If you are looking to store the results in a server/database and be able to view them any time you could use [IPN](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro).  [IPN](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro) would send the POST of details to your system once the payment is completed and you could query your system any time for the status.

Comment: Thank You for your quick response it helped a lot. :) But currently I am not working on that issue so haven't applied it properly.